# is it possible a button confirm the imageView ?(game-charcter)

Tags: android, button, imageview

I have 9 imageview (9 characters) game characters so I can put  yellow ring on the Picture  if I choose one of them well I have at the bottom ok button how Can I made this button to confirm the character after that it will intent to another activity but I don't know how to confirm my selection

```
 imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    imageView3 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    imageView4 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
    imageView5 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
    imageView6 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
    imageView7 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView7);
    imageView8 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView8);
    imageView9 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView9);
    button =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {



        }
    });

}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Drawable highlight = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.highlight);

    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.imageView :
            imageView.setBackground(highlight);
            imageView2.setBackground(null);
            imageView3.setBackground(null);
            imageView4.setBackground(null);
            imageView5.setBackground(null);
            imageView6.setBackground(null);
            imageView7.setBackground(null);
            imageView8.setBackground(null);
            imageView9.setBackground(null);
            break;

        case R.id.imageView2 :
            imageView2.setBackground(highlight);
            imageView.setBackground(null);
            imageView3.setBackground(null);
            imageView4.setBackground(null);
            imageView5.setBackground(null);
            imageView6.setBackground(null);
            imageView7.setBackground(null);
            imageView8.setBackground(null);
            imageView9.setBackground(null);

            break;

        case R.id.imageView3 :
            imageView3.setBackground(highlight);
            imageView.setBackground(null);
            imageView2.setBackground(null);
            imageView4.setBackground(null);
            imageView5.setBackground(null);
            imageView6.setBackground(null);
            imageView7.setBackground(null);
            imageView8.setBackground(null);
            imageView9.setBackground(null);
            break;


        case R.id.imageView4 :
            imageView4.setBackground(highlight);
            imageView.setBackground(null);
            imageView3.setBackground(null);
            imageView2.setBackground(null);
            imageView5.setBackground(null);
            imageView6.setBackground(null);
            imageView7.setBackground(null);
            imageView8.setBackground(null);
            imageView9.setBackground(null);
            break;

        case R.id.imageView5 :
            imageView5.setBackground(highlight);
            imageView.setBackground(null);
            imageView3.setBackground(null);
            imageView4.setBackground(null);
            imageView2.setBackground(null);
            imageView6.setBackground(null);
            imageView7.setBackground(null);
            imageView8.setBackground(null);
            imageView9.setBackground(null);
            break;

        case R.id.imageView6 :
            imageView6.setBackground(highlight);
            imageView.setBackground(null);
            imageView3.setBackground(null);
            imageView4.setBackground(null);
            imageView5.setBackground(null);
            imageView2.setBackground(null);
            imageView7.setBackground(null);
            imageView8.setBackground(null);
            imageView9.setBackground(null);
            break;

        case R.id.imageView7 :
            imageView7.setBackground(highlight);
            imageView.setBackground(null);
            imageView3.setBackground(null);
            imageView4.setBackground(null);
            imageView5.setBackground(null);
            imageView6.setBackground(null);
            imageView2.setBackground(null);
            imageView8.setBackground(null);
            imageView9.setBackground(null);
            break;

        case R.id.imageView8 :
            imageView8.setBackground(highlight);
            imageView.setBackground(null);
            imageView3.setBackground(null);
            imageView4.setBackground(null);
            imageView5.setBackground(null);
            imageView6.setBackground(null);
            imageView7.setBackground(null);
            imageView2.setBackground(null);
            imageView9.setBackground(null);
            break;

        case R.id.imageView9 :
            imageView9.setBackground(highlight);
            imageView.setBackground(null);
            imageView3.setBackground(null);
            imageView4.setBackground(null);
            imageView5.setBackground(null);
            imageView6.setBackground(null);
            imageView7.setBackground(null);
            imageView8.setBackground(null);
            imageView2.setBackground(null);
            break;



    }
}
```

highlight.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <shape
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:shape="ring"
      android:innerRadius="50dp"
      android:thickness="10dp"
      android:useLevel="false">

   <solid android:color="#ff0004" />

   </shape>
```

Comment: Make a variable selectedGameCharacter and set it in each switch-case to the value you want.

Comment: i want to press the ok button then the selected character confirms i don't know what to write in button.clicklistener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      if(isSelected(imageView)){
          //image view 1 is selected
      }else if(isSelected(imageView2)){
          //image view 2 is selected
      }else if(isSelected(imageView3)){
          //image view 3 is selected
      }
      .... // continue for the rest of the imageviews
   }
});


private boolean isSelected(Imageview iv){
   Drawable background = iv.getBackground();
   if(background != null)
      return true;
   else 
      return false;
}
```

Comment: y getbackground ?

Comment: cause u r setting ur image veiws's background :P

Comment: ohh lol sry :D haha and thx and look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40038661/how-can-i-change-shape-ring-color-with-a-one-button

Answer (score 0):

What I meant was the following:

```
private int selectedCharacter = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    imageView3 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    imageView4 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
    imageView5 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
    imageView6 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
    imageView7 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView7);
    imageView8 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView8);
    imageView9 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView9);
    button =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(selectedCharacter == 1) {
                // whatever
            } else if(selectedCharacter == 2) {
                // etc.
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Drawable highlight = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.highlight);

    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.imageView :
            selectedCharacter = 1;
            imageView.setBackground(highlight);
            imageView2.setBackground(null);
            imageView3.setBackground(null);
            imageView4.setBackground(null);
            imageView5.setBackground(null);
            imageView6.setBackground(null);
            imageView7.setBackground(null);
            imageView8.setBackground(null);
            imageView9.setBackground(null);
            break;

        case R.id.imageView2 :
            selectedCharacter = 2;
            imageView2.setBackground(highlight);
            imageView.setBackground(null);
            imageView3.setBackground(null);
            imageView4.setBackground(null);
            imageView5.setBackground(null);
            imageView6.setBackground(null);
            imageView7.setBackground(null);
            imageView8.setBackground(null);
            imageView9.setBackground(null);
            break;

        case R.id.imageView3 :
            selectedCharacter = 3;
            imageView3.setBackground(highlight);
            imageView.setBackground(null);
            imageView2.setBackground(null);
            imageView4.setBackground(null);
            imageView5.setBackground(null);
            imageView6.setBackground(null);
            imageView7.setBackground(null);
            imageView8.setBackground(null);
            imageView9.setBackground(null);
            break;


        case R.id.imageView4 :
            selectedCharacter = 4;
            imageView4.setBackground(highlight);
            imageView.setBackground(null);
            imageView3.setBackground(null);
            imageView2.setBackground(null);
            imageView5.setBackground(null);
            imageView6.setBackground(null);
            imageView7.setBackground(null);
            imageView8.setBackground(null);
            imageView9.setBackground(null);
            break;

        case R.id.imageView5 :
            selectedCharacter = 5;
            imageView5.setBackground(highlight);
            imageView.setBackground(null);
            imageView3.setBackground(null);
            imageView4.setBackground(null);
            imageView2.setBackground(null);
            imageView6.setBackground(null);
            imageView7.setBackground(null);
            imageView8.setBackground(null);
            imageView9.setBackground(null);
            break;

        case R.id.imageView6 :
            selectedCharacter = 6;
            imageView6.setBackground(highlight);
            imageView.setBackground(null);
            imageView3.setBackground(null);
            imageView4.setBackground(null);
            imageView5.setBackground(null);
            imageView2.setBackground(null);
            imageView7.setBackground(null);
            imageView8.setBackground(null);
            imageView9.setBackground(null);
            break;

        case R.id.imageView7 :
            selectedCharacter = 7;
            imageView7.setBackground(highlight);
            imageView.setBackground(null);
            imageView3.setBackground(null);
            imageView4.setBackground(null);
            imageView5.setBackground(null);
            imageView6.setBackground(null);
            imageView2.setBackground(null);
            imageView8.setBackground(null);
            imageView9.setBackground(null);
            break;

        case R.id.imageView8 :
            selectedCharacter = 8;
            imageView8.setBackground(highlight);
            imageView.setBackground(null);
            imageView3.setBackground(null);
            imageView4.setBackground(null);
            imageView5.setBackground(null);
            imageView6.setBackground(null);
            imageView7.setBackground(null);
            imageView2.setBackground(null);
            imageView9.setBackground(null);
            break;

        case R.id.imageView9 :
            selectedCharacter = 9;
            imageView9.setBackground(highlight);
            imageView.setBackground(null);
            imageView3.setBackground(null);
            imageView4.setBackground(null);
            imageView5.setBackground(null);
            imageView6.setBackground(null);
            imageView7.setBackground(null);
            imageView8.setBackground(null);
            imageView2.setBackground(null);
            break;
    }
}
```

but @ik024's answer is nice too.